# Javascript is not adding innerText values

Tags: javascript, local-storage, contenteditable

```js
var totalStatus = document.getElementById ('total_status');
var upcomingStatus = document.getElementById ('status_upcoming');
var progressStatus = document.getElementById ('status_progress');

totalStatus.innerHTML =
  parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);

// Get Upcoming Projects
function getUpcoming () {
  if (localStorage.getItem ('Upcoming') === null) {
    upcomingStatus.textContent = '[Upcoming]';
  } else {
    upcomingStatus.textContent = localStorage.getItem ('Upcoming');
  }
}

// Get Projects in Progress
function getProgress () {
  if (localStorage.getItem ('In Progress') === null) {
    progressStatus.textContent = '[Progress]';
  } else {
    progressStatus.textContent = localStorage.getItem ('In Progress');
  }
}

// Set Projects in progress
function setProgress (e) {
  if (e.type === 'keypress') {
    // Make sure enter is pressed
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
      localStorage.setItem ('In Progress', e.target.innerText);
      progressStatus.blur ();
    }
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem ('In Progress', e.target.innerText);
  }
}

// Set Upcoming Projects
function setUpcoming (e) {
  if (e.type === 'keypress') {
    // Make sure enter is pressed
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
      localStorage.setItem ('Upcoming', e.target.innerText);
      upcomingStatus.blur ();
    }
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem ('Upcoming', e.target.innerText);
  }
}

upcomingStatus.addEventListener ('keypress', setUpcoming);
upcomingStatus.addEventListener ('blur', setUpcoming);

progressStatus.addEventListener ('keypress', setProgress);
progressStatus.addEventListener ('blur', setProgress);

getUpcoming ();, 
getProgress ();
```

```html
<div class="projects-status">
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="status_progress" contenteditable="true"></span>
    <span class="status-type">In Progress</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="status_upcoming" contenteditable="true"></span>
    <span class="status-type">Upcoming</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="total_status"></span>
    <span class="status-type">Total Projects</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

While I was editing the upcoming and progress projects, I wanted the total projects to update, but it shows NaN. I think it is taking the values from my code where there is no value. But in the inspector, the values(innerText) of progress and upcoming projects are still being received. What should I change in my code?

Comment: What is the value returned from the line `parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `innerHTML` of `totalStatus` in the `setProgress()` and `setUpcoming()` functions. This is because when the page is loaded, both the `upcomingStatus` and `progressStatus` variables are not numbers. Maybe this code would work:

```js
var totalStatus = document.getElementById ('total_status');
var upcomingStatus = document.getElementById ('status_upcoming');
var progressStatus = document.getElementById ('status_progress');

// Set Projects in progress
function setProgress (e) {
  if (e.type === 'keypress') {
    // Make sure enter is pressed
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
      // localStorage.setItem ('In Progress', e.target.innerText);
      progressStatus.blur ();
      totalStatus.innerHTML = parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);
    }
  } else {
    // localStorage.setItem ('In Progress', e.target.innerText);
    totalStatus.innerHTML = parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);
  }
}

// Set Upcoming Projects
function setUpcoming (e) {
  if (e.type === 'keypress') {
    // Make sure enter is pressed
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
      // localStorage.setItem ('Upcoming', e.target.innerText);
      upcomingStatus.blur ();
      totalStatus.innerHTML = parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);
    }
  } else {
  //  localStorage.setItem ('Upcoming', e.target.innerText);
    totalStatus.innerHTML = parseInt (progressStatus.innerText) + parseInt (upcomingStatus.innerText);
  }
}

upcomingStatus.addEventListener ('keypress', setUpcoming);
upcomingStatus.addEventListener ('blur', setUpcoming);

progressStatus.addEventListener ('keypress', setProgress);
progressStatus.addEventListener ('blur', setProgress);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div class="projects-status">
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="status_progress" contenteditable="true">[progress] </span>
    <span class="status-type">In Progress</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="status_upcoming" contenteditable="true">[upcoming] </span>
    <span class="status-type">Upcoming</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-status">
    <span class="status-number" id="total_status"></span>
    <span class="status-type">Total Projects</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have removed and commented some of the localstorage properties due to security reasons.